# How do you execute a query in Sequel Pro?

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I want to execute a query in a MySQL DB using Sequel Pro, but I do not see a <kbd>Run</kbd> button.

How do I execute my query?

[image]

Comment: It's right there in your screenshot. Middle-right, `Ejecutar seleción`.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to execute the selected Query.

*Alternatively*, use the dropdown that appears at the bottom right of the query editor and select `Run Current` or `Run Previous` depending on where your text cursor is.

Answer (score 12):

Based on [Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/Keyboard_Shortcuts):

**Run all queries**     <kbd>⌥</kbd>   <kbd>⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>

**Run current query or selection**  <kbd>⌅</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 9):

Use the drop down button on the right side, underneath the textarea.

Should have the following options:

- Run Current Query
- Run All Queries

Answer (score 2):

Came here to find ⌘ + return to execute a query (like MySQL Workbench).

Found that I can map using mac Key bindings with the names of `Run Current Query` and `Run Previous Query`.

If you want to do it via terminal it would be (untested):

```
 defaults write com.sequelpro.SequelPro NSUserKeyEquivalents '{
        "Run Current Query" = "@\\U21a9";
        "Run Previous Query" = "@\\U21a9";
    }'
```

Note: you may have to restart the app.